# Google ReCaptcha doesn't display in Safari 5.1.10

Tags: javascript, php, safari, recaptcha

Hi i have this code for Google ReCaptcha:

```
<div class="captcha">
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=code">
 </script>
 <noscript>
 <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6code"
     height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
 <textarea id="recaptcha_challenge_field" name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3"  cols="40">
 </textarea>
 <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
     value="manual_challenge">
 </noscript>

 </div>
```

but this doesn't display in Safari Mac 5.1.10 Snow Leopard. Only afte a reload it display the Captcha.

Comment: I have this same problem at the bottom of this page: http://www.jamonit.org/event-registration/?ee=63

Any ideas?

Comment: no i'm sorry. Now i use a different captcha code... [link](http://sweetcaptcha.com/)